No ApexPage named CommunitiesLanding digital experience deployment
I am trying to deploy digital experience metadata. Default index page is CommunitiesLanding (which is default sf visualforce page). I am getting error Error: In field: indexPage - no ApexPage named CommunitiesLanding.
Here is my metadata. I am checking org and there are no CommunitiesLanding. But if I manually create any site CommunitiesLanding, Login and other similar vf pages are created. What can I do to deploy site with CommunitiesLanding page?
Actually no default visualforce pages exist before creating site.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomSite xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <active>true</active>
    <allowStandardPortalPages>true</allowStandardPortalPages>
    <browserXssProtection>true</browserXssProtection>
    <clickjackProtectionLevel>SameOriginOnly</clickjackProtectionLevel>
    <contentSniffingProtection>true</contentSniffingProtection>
    <indexPage>CommunitiesLanding</indexPage>
    <masterLabel>Test</masterLabel>
    <referrerPolicyOriginWhenCrossOrigin>true</referrerPolicyOriginWhenCrossOrigin>
    <siteType>ChatterNetwork</siteType>
    <urlPathPrefix>test</urlPathPrefix>
</CustomSite>


The UI takes care of everything for you, but if you're using the API, you need to include those extra components. In other words, you'll need to deploy the Visualforce page and its controller as well.
